# Finding elements that repeat in a SLL

Tags: c++, list, singly-linked-list

This function computes the number of occurrences of the given element in a Singly linked list, and if the value is not in the list or the list is empty return 0. The current list has `{97,92,75,97,97}`.
It should return 3 but my code only returns 1 what is the problem with my code?

```
template <typename Data_t>
size_t SLinkedList<Data_t>::freq(Data_t element) {
    
    Node* ptr;
    ptr = _head;
    
    
    if(empty()) return 0;
    
    while (ptr != nullptr) {
        size_t count = 0;
        if( ptr->_data == element) {
            ptr = ptr->_next;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ptr = ptr->_next;` and `return count;` are both in the wrong places.

Comment: Don't be too keen on using TLAs everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues in this loop:

```
while (ptr != nullptr) {
        size_t count = 0;
        if( ptr->_data == element) {
            ptr = ptr->_next;
            count++;
        }

        return count;
    }
```

You are only moving to the next node if the element is found.

In addition, you are initializing `count` inside the loop, and returning `count` from inside the loop unconditionally. This means the loop either returns 0 or 1 depending on whether the first node contains the element you're looking for.

---

The correct way to write the function would be:

```
template <typename Data_t>
size_t SLinkedList<Data_t>::freq(Data_t element) {

    size_t count = 0;
    
    for (Node *ptr = _head; ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->_next;) {
        if( ptr->_data == element) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```